# Krusader doesn't save FTP password

Tags: ftp, krusader

I need to type the FTP password always, although I have checked the `remember password` option.

What could be wrong ??

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://forum.krusader.org/viewtopic.php?p=11700) ?

Comment: @pl1nk this looks like solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A workaround posted from Krusader [forum](http://forum.krusader.org/viewtopic.php?p=11700).

1. Login to the FTP host
2. Add this FTP host to favorites
3. Quit Krusader
4. Run Krusader
5. Select the FTP host from favorites (the one previously added)
6. Enter the FTP host password and select the option to remember it

Now the FTP host is in favorites with no need to re-enter the password.

Answer (score 2):

edit bookmarks,
write the password in the URL :

ftp://username:password@sftp.foo.org/